# Android : Display Photos and Videos at dynamic time interval

Tags: android, timer, thread-safety, video-streaming

I want to display number of photos and videos at dynamic time interval. My conditions are

1) Display photo at dynamic interval
2) When Video is there, play the video and stop the task, 
3) After playing video resume thread or whatever we have used.

I tried it using Thread, but video is giving problem, and thread behaves unexpected. Is there any better solution or suggestion,

Following is my code in MainActivity.class

```
timer = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int z = 0; z < userStories.size(); z++) {

                    Log.e("File Name--->", userStories.get(z).getFileName());
                    Log.e("File TYPEEEE--->", userStories.get(z).getType());
                    if (userStories.get(z).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("photo")) {
                        Log.e("SLEEEEEPppp-->", "SO GAYA THREAD");
                        sleep(Long.parseLong(userStories.get(z).getDisplayTime()) * 1000);
                        final int finalZ = z;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                video_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                        .load(userStories.get(finalZ).getFileName())
                                        .into(image);
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (userStories.get(z).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
                        /*synchronized (this) {
                             Log.e("Waitttttt-->", "Wait kar riya he...");
                                wait();
                            }*/
                        final int finalZ2 = z;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                video_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                String VideoURL = userStories.get(finalZ2).getFileName();
                                uri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(VideoURL)) {

                                    video_view.setVideoURI(uri);
                                    video_view.requestFocus();
                                    video_view.start();

                                    video_view.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                            pauseWork = false;

                                        }
                                    });

                                    video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                            Log.e("VIDEooooooo--->", "Completeeeee");
                                            Log.e("Thread Notifyyyy--->", "Hooo Gayaaaaaa");
                                            timer.interrupt();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        /*synchronized (timer) {
                            Log.e("WAITTTTTT-->", "WAIT KAR RIYA HE");
                            timer.wait();
                        }*/
                    }

                    final int finalZ1 = z;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < userStories.size(); i++) {
                                if (i == finalZ1) {
                                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));
                                } else {
                                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I think you can use JobScheduler. @Shruti

Comment: Post what you have tried until now

Comment: @Akshay , i have posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use handler instead, try code below. First you have to call CallNext() method.

```
private void bindHandler() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            callNext();
            Log.e("In HANDLER------>", "HANDLER");
        }
    }, DISPLAY_LENGTH * 1000);
}



  private void callNext() {
    if (counter < statusModel.getStories().get(position).getUserStories().size()) {
        if (statusModel.getStories().get(position).getUserStories().get(counter).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("photo")) {
            Log.e("PHOTOOOO--->", "PHOTOOOOO");

            String photo = statusModel.getStories().get(position).getUserStories().get(counter).getFileName();
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            video_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(photo)
                    .into(image);
            counter++;
            DISPLAY_LENGTH = Long.parseLong(statusModel.getStories().get(position).getUserStories().get(counter).getDisplayTime());
            Log.e("DIAPLAY TIME--->", String.valueOf(DISPLAY_LENGTH));
            bindHandler();
        } else {
            if (statusModel.getStories().get(position).getUserStories().get(counter).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
                Log.e("VIDEOOOO--->", "VIDEOOOOO");
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                video_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String VideoURL = statusModel.getStories().get(position).getUserStories().get(counter).getFileName();
                uri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(VideoURL)) {
                    video_view.setVideoURI(uri);
                    video_view.requestFocus();
                    video_view.start();
                    video_view.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                        }
                    });

                    video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            Log.e("VIDEooooooo--->", "Completeeeee");

   Log.e("Thread Notifyyyy--->", "Hooo Gayaaaaaa");
                            counter++;
                            callNext();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: let me try and i will get back to you, thanks for answer.